# Styling is broken on CV pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, developer-story, traditional-view

Styling is broken on [CV pages](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/grzegorz-zur), AKA the traditional views of the developer story.

Here is how it looks now (click on the image to enlarge it):

[image: broken styling]

Here is how it looked before:

[image: correct styling]

It is broken since April 8<sup>th</sup> or earlier.

Comment: To be more specific the traditional CV style is a mess. The story link seems to be ok

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oops, that page was missing our shared CSS library. Fix is going out shortly, thanks for the report.